# How to change logo and menu on genesis Wordpress if URL contains a certain string?

Tags: php, wordpress, genesis

I´m using Genesis framework on Wordpress and want to change the logo and primary menu when the URL contains a certain string. For example if the URL is http://example.com/testing I want one logo and menu for example.com, and another one when the URL has "testing" in it.

I´ve tried this for changing the logo:

```
    function new_headerimage(){
    if(basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) == 'testing') {
        echo '<div class="testing-header"><a href="http://example.com/testing"><img src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/logotest.jpeg" alt="logo image" /></a></div>';
   } else {
       echo '<div class="original-header"><a href="http://example.com/"><img src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/logotest2.jpeg" alt="logo" /></a></div>';
}}
add_action('genesis_header', 'new_headerimage');
```

But it will only show the new logo at example.com/testing and not example.com/testing/test2. Any tips how to make it just search if the URL contains the word "testing", and not only if testing is the basename?

Answer (score 0):

Try as follows

```
 function new_headerimage(){
        if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'testing') !== false ) {

             echo '<div class="original-header"><a href="http://example.com/"><img src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/logotest2.jpeg" alt="logo" /></a></div>';
       } else {

           echo '<div class="testing-header"><a href="http://example.com/testing"><img src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/logotest.jpeg" alt="logo image" /></a></div>';

    }
}
add_action('genesis_header', 'new_headerimage');
```